# Typescript: How to create tuple with 2 items where 2nd item uses value of the 1st one as a key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, tuples

I would like to create an array tuple with values ['account', 'accountOne'], that are using existing Types, but second tuple value should contain values based on selection of the first one.

Some example code below:

```
interface RootState {
  account: Account;
  movies: Movies;
  config: Config;
}
 
interface Account {
  accountOne: 'something',
  accountTwo: '1'
}

interface Movies {
  moviesOne: 'something',
  moviesTwo: 'something' 
}

interface Config {
  configOne: 'something',
  configTwo: '123' 
}

export type ModuleProp = keyof RootState;
  

// This is some pseudo code, to show the idea, but I could not make it work    
// It gives error: Tuple type arguments circularly reference themselves
export type ModulesTuple = [ModuleProp, keyof RootState[ModulesTuple[0]]
    
// It would be used as
function fetchSomething({page: number, vuexModuleProp: ModulesTuple}){

  const [module, moduleProp] = vuexModuleProp
  // rest of the code
}

fetchSomething({
  page: 1,
  vuexModuleProp: ['movies', 'accountOne'] // ERROR
})

fetchSomething({
  page: 1,
  vuexModuleProp: ['movies', 'moviesOne'] // GOOD TO GO
})
```

Current code gives error of: Tuple type arguments circularly reference themselves

The idea is that if you select 'account' as first tuple, second selection should be 'accountOne' or 'accountTwo', which are nested keys of other interfaces (Movies, Account, Config) in RootState interface.

Not really sure if that is possible with Typescript, but would greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).

```
interface RootState {
  account: Account;
  movies: Movies;
  config: Config;
}
 
interface Account {
  accountOne: 'something',
  accountTwo: '1'
}

interface Movies {
  moviesOne: 'something',
  moviesTwo: 'something' 
}

interface Config {
  configOne: 'something',
  configTwo: '123' 
}

// All available modules
type ModuleKeys = keyof RootState;

// Pick a module interface based on type of `T`
type ModuleProps<T extends ModuleKeys> = T extends 'account'
  ? Account
  : T extends 'movies'
  ? Movies
  : T extends 'config'
  ? Config
  : never;

// Creates a tuple where the second type is based on the first type, where the first type is automatically inferred from `T`.
type ModuleTuple<T extends ModuleKeys> = [T, keyof ModuleProps<T>];

// Guard the `T` type to be one of `ModuleKeys`, where it is passed to `ModuleTuple<T>`, where it creates the conditional tuple.
function fetchSomething<T extends ModuleKeys>({ page, vuexModuleProp }: { page: number, vuexModuleProp: ModuleTuple<T> }): any {
  const [moduleKey, moduleProps] = vuexModuleProp;
  console.log(page, moduleKey, moduleProps);
}

fetchSomething({
  page: 1,
  vuexModuleProp: ['movies', 'accountOne']  // ERROR
});

fetchSomething({
  page: 1,
  vuexModuleProp: ['movies', 'moviesOne']   // GOOD TO GO
});
```

Check the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=37&ssc=129&pln=37&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoHt1gMpjpZAbwChllEF0BXcALmQEEFKawBuU5AW3QDdgIAZ3oBZPgMEcylEDGABzegGF0shRwC+pYqEixEKJi3BFOFauADyICPQDkg9FwhgAFqHl2ANGeYWwACoA7uj2AIx2xFo64NDwSMhi-EKmZDzJgta2yA5OLu4gnj5p4kLBoTmOzm4edshRxDF68SgqavKpyDJy8ln2Vfm1xV2qPeXhAEwAzHUNxAD084wANsvkvHDAy3AARssoPAAmVPuCxGAAngAOKGLH+wDSEBeCyAC8yADWz+gwaJg4PCQDgLJYABWACE+5G46HuKF0cQMyB2cEEEEOyFUyEuNyxfwABgECedrrc4ScIGCoOgroIADwBZAQAAekBAh1ed0pTxeAD53sgmaz2ZycuZWJEyAB+Rh+VicejCtkQDmvOzpCRS5CypISRVC5kqtU5boKbWyto9A02XjQEGLZBKKAQfApOA4qhXfbIIKuaAoNwodEyTG4hGvVHozHYoPIORQQRgHFkry+-0unH++PARPJ8PIYCvOBUMBOfCQuCrC6F2TQF2YmA0rjIIkEgB0pLx3P2AS9+0ZRtFXIpj2eggFHwA2gE098Lr9EqOqTS6Yy+QBdB1LADiVDgUDD2bbKbxZZRKFUl8JPYgvMEBLTfoDheTReQVzR0Zx6Fbt773oQOuj7pi+wDJggLpuq8cahuBwCqFWnqAZ2MA0AgYAISA8YuAgrjYHkNSFIOIqqmKt73nyAAUhAfnA8gQGmvBUKyt7UrSyAaPQtGfgx9AgFQXA7NATEsSybGrqIy4AQOAQChoACU9BwCANYkNIqhJsgU5HDyzxprp+zsXSG6CsxrHLsZUgjCAjj7O2yzoPIVG8YxsLwryBmWauggKZojQwLh+GEQUznqXRfHIGEwzmeJ3m0vQU4aqUgjeOK8pWDYdimcgjoAKKoKglioFEfkBUFBHVKFNGcK59DRZwsUSQl2nJRkaVtRIWTZWQuW7pYlgACJCpYyA7pYpVsEAA).

Comment: Thats great, exactly what I was looking for. Really appreciate explanation about conditional Generics.